# Is it possible to remove a message from a ServiceBus topic?

Tags: azureservicebus

Let's say a message gets posted to a topic.  The topic has 5 subscriptions.  Is it possible to delete the messages in a single call?
Hopefully I don't have to go through each subscription seperately looking for the messages...?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible. Messages can only be sent to a topic but not received. A message from topic is copied to all the subscriptions that have a matching filter.

I would not advise deleting anything after it was posted to a topic. Topics and subscriptions used to communicate discrete events. Something that has taken place and immutable.